# Does using a globally declared variable in one function stop it from being used in another?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, declaration, variable-declaration

I'm trying to understand why one version of my code works and another one doesn't. I've defined var numbers globally so I figured if I ran function sumArray() then it would pass in the elements but it always returned 0. It was only when I defined it AGAIN closer to the function sumArray() that it calculated correctly.

Does using the variables numbers for the printReverse() function disable it from being used again in sumArray()? If you comment out `var numbers = [2, 2, 3];` then you'll see it returns 0 in the console.

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
var result = 0;

function printReverse() {
  var reversed = [];

  while (numbers.length) {
    //push the element that's removed/popped from the array into the reversed variable
    reversed.push(numbers.pop());
  }
  //stop the function 
  return reversed;
}
//print the results of the function printReverse()
console.log(printReverse());

var numbers = [2, 2, 3];

function sumArray() {
  //pass each element from the array into the function
  numbers.forEach(function(value) {
    //calculate the sum of var result + the value passed through and store the sum in var result
    result += value;
  });

  //return and print the sum
  return result;
}

//print the results of the function sumArray()
console.log(sumArray());
```

Comment: pop modifies the original array, hence your array contains no elements after calling the printReverse function

Comment: Ahh! I didn't know that pop permanently changed the original array. I'll definitely keep that in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(When you have commented out the `var numbers = [2,2,3]`)

The `pop` method modifies the original array, hence you have no elements left to when you reach the sumArray function.

Instead you can use the [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method

```js
numbers.reverse(); //this can completely replace the printReverse function
```

Comment: I was hesitant on using .reverse() because I wasn't sure it was going to produce the result I wanted. I changed my code around to be able to use it and both approaches yield the same result but .reverse() definitely works better for the overall goal of my original code. Thank you!